# Symfony 4 / Doctrine: Dynamic table name on entity => function with find () OK but createQueryBuilder () NOK

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

I have a database composed (among others) of tables of statistics dynamically named by period:
     MY_TABLE_2019_01
     MY_TABLE_2019_02
     ...
     MY_TABLE_2019_10

The idea is to create a single entity and manage it dynamically.

I manage to handle the call to the entity dynamically by setting the name of the table. When using the *find()* method, I do not have problems, the name change is done correctly and I can make several changes in the controller without encountering an error, however, since a call to a *createQueryBuilder()*, only the initial configuration is taken into account and the change of the name of the table is not taken into account after, yet there is a *clear()* performed ?

**Question**: Why with a *find()* the change is functional but not with the *createQueryBuilder()* ?

## My Code

My entity, classic but no table name

```php
    namespace App\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
    * @ORM\Table()
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MyTableRepository") 
    */
    class MyTable {
        /**
        * @ORM\Id()
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
        * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer")
        */
        private $id;
```

### CASE N ° 1, it works! :)

#### In my controller :

```php
        $oEntityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $metadata = $oEntityManager->getClassMetadata(MyTable::class);
        $metadata->setPrimaryTable(array('name' => 'MY_TABLE_2019_02')); //-- Dynamically manage the table
        echo $metadata->getTableName(); //-- 'MY_TABLE_2019_02'
        //--
        $oMyTable = $oEntityManager->getRepository(MyTable::class);
        //--
        $aRetour = $oMyTable->find(1); //-- SELECT ... FROM MY_TABLE_2019_02... OK
        $oMyTable->clear();
        //--
        $metadata->setPrimaryTable(array('name' => 'MY_TABLE_2019_06')); //-- Dynamically manage the table
        echo $metadata->getTableName(); //-- 'MY_TABLE_2019_06' OK
        $aRetour = $oMyTable->find(1); //-- SELECT ... FROM MY_TABLE_2019_06... OK ! IS GOOD :)
```

### CASE N ° 2, it doesn't work! :(

#### In my repository :

```php
        public function myFunction(): array {

            $oRequete = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')->setMaxResults(10);

            return $oRequete->getQuery()
                            ->getResult();
        }
```

#### In my controller :

```php
        $oEntityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $metadata = $oEntityManager->getClassMetadata(MyTable::class);
        $metadata->setPrimaryTable(array('name' => 'MY_TABLE_2019_02')); //-- Dynamically manage the table
        echo $metadata->getTableName(); //-- 'MY_TABLE_2019_02' OK
        //--
        $oMyTable = $oEntityManager->getRepository(MyTable::class);
        //--
        $aRetour = $oMyTable->myFunction(); //-- SELECT ... FROM MY_TABLE_2019_02... OK
        $oMyTable->clear();
        //--
        $metadata->setPrimaryTable(array('name' => 'MY_TABLE_2019_06')); //-- Dynamically manage the table
        echo $metadata->getTableName(); //-- 'MY_TABLE_2019_06' OK !!!!
        $aRetour = $oMyTable->myFunction(); //-- SELECT ... FROM MY_TABLE_2019_02... NOK !!!!!!!!! table name not change here !?
```

In this case 2, when I make *$metadata->getTableName()* I have a valid return, here 'MY_TABLE_2019_06', but when I call *$oMyTable->myFunction()*, the request generated via the *createQueryBuilder()* does not does not change ?

Do you have a solution or a research track to give me?

Comment: And why not just use a single table? How much data do you have there? (How many rows, billions?)

Comment: If you really want to continue using many tables look for the LOAD_METADATA Doctrine event in which you can manipulate the entity’s metadata dynamically. God forbid, don’t do this inside a controller.

Comment: @emix : Each table contains several millions of entries, originally there was only one table but as soon as we request, especially with filters over periods, the response time was much too long. (MySQL)  
:/ I already manage, in this case, the metadata and actually, in my controller :( ( _$metadata->setPrimaryTable()_ )  
I understand that the management of the database is not ideal, If you have another method of data management, I am listening to you :)
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @NicolasLEGOUFFE would it be possible for you to post a full answer with your solution, please? I'm working on a similar challenge and would like to learn more from yours. Thanks in advance for your support.